# Mobile Lightbox?

Tags: jquery, html, lightbox

I'm looking for a mobile lightbox that I can use my existing image links with.

For example I have a big page of images, each of them displayed with `<a href="image.jpg"><img src="image.jpg></a>`. I want to be able to "convert" them all to be a lightbox, so when someone touches one of the images it will pop up and have a little X button so they can close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check http://visuallightbox.com/jquery-thickbox-iphone-demo.html

Comment: Free only for non-commercial use, expensive license, and cumbersome to use for a programmer (geared for use by non-programmers).

Comment: You might wanna check the time-stamp. It was answered almost a year ago when all those fancy scripts you are comparing this one might not have even existed. Good luck with scoring high reps!

Comment: Fails to accomplish anything different from standard lightboxes on Android - still opens the box off-screen, same usability problems.